# How to show/hide google chart's tooltip programatically?

Tags: google-visualization

Is there any way to show/hide (open/close) google chart tooltip programatically? My tooltip is **html enabled**, trigger by '**selection**'. I am trying to add a close icon to the tooltip.

Answer (score 11):

You can show it using `setSelection()` method, for example:

```
var options = {
    ....
    tooltip: { trigger: 'selection' }
    ...
}

chart.setSelection([{row:0, column:1}]);
```

See [example at jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ketuw/1/edit).

And hide it using empty object:

```
chart.setSelection([{}]);
```

See [example at jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ketuw/2/edit).

Comment: To clarify: this *only* works when `tooltip.trigger` is set to `'selection'`.

Comment: You can also use `{ trigger: 'both' }` which will show tooltips on 'hover' and when programmatically calling `setSelection` -- see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24771024/426790