# Google Chart Timeline Tooltip will not stay open on click

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, tooltip, timeline

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24770513/how-can-i-use-html-tooltip-with-triggerboth-in-google-charts) solution...

```
'tooltip': 
{
   'isHtml': true,
   'trigger': 'both'
},
```

...adding 'both' to the tooltip trigger, is not working for this code...

```
function createChart() 
{
    // Include chart timeline files
    google.charts.load("current", {packages:["timeline","controls"]});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawDashboard);

    function drawDashboard() 
    {
        var i = 0;
        var type = "AP";

        var APListURL = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('NXE Action Plan Tracker')/items";
        var PMListURL = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('NXE Action Plans Temp Processing')/items";
        var currentListURL = APListURL;

        var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard( document.getElementById('timeline') );

        var currentTime = new Date(Date.now());
        var oneWeek = new Date(Date.now() + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var fourWeek = new Date(Date.now() + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 4));
        var sixMonth = new Date(Date.now() + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 24));

        // Add columns to data table
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'System' });
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Action' });
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'tooltip','p': {'html': true}});
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'style'});
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });

        // Create range slider
        var timelineRangeSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
            'controlType': 'ChartRangeFilter',
            'containerId': 'timeline-filter',
            'state': 
            {
                'range': 
                {
                    'start': currentTime,
                    'end':   fourWeek                   
                }
            },
            'options': 
            {
                'filterColumnIndex': 4,
                'ui': 
                {
                    'chartType': 'ScatterChart',
                    'chartOptions': 
                    {
                        'width': '100%',
                        'height': '115',
                        'chartArea': 
                        {
                            'width': '80%', // make sure this is the same for the chart and control so the axes align right
                            'height': '80%'
                        },
                        'hAxis': 
                        {
                            'baselineColor': 'none'
                        }
                    },
                    'chartView': 
                    {
                        'columns': [4,4]
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        // Create timeline
        var timeline = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
            'chartType': 'Timeline',
            'containerId': 'timeline-chart',
            'options': 
            {
                'timeline': {'showBarLabels': false},
                'width': '100%',
                'height': '570',
                'tooltip': 
                {
                    'isHtml': true,
                    'trigger': 'both'
                },
                'chartArea': 
                {
                    'width': '80%', // make sure this is the same for the chart and control so the axes align right
                    'height': '80%'
                }, 
            },
            'view': 
            {
                'columns': [0,1,2,3,4,5]
            }           
        });

        // Changing range
        changeRange = function(range) 
        {
            switch(range)
            {
                case "oneWeek":

                    timelineRangeSlider.setState({'range':{'start': currentTime, 'end': oneWeek}});
                    break;

                case "fourWeek":

                    timelineRangeSlider.setState({'range':{'start': currentTime, 'end': fourWeek}});
                    break;

                case "sixMonth":

                    timelineRangeSlider.setState({'range':{'start': currentTime, 'end': sixMonth}});
                    break;

                default:
                    console.log('no bueno!');
                    break;
            }

            timelineRangeSlider.draw();
        };  

        // Add current time to timeline
        dataTable.addRow(["Current Time", "Now", "<div style='white-space: nowrap; padding:5px;'>Current Day: "+new Date(Date.now()).toDateString()+"</div>" ,'blue', new Date(Date.now()), new Date(Date.now())]);

        // Add items to the timeline
        getTimelineData();
        function getTimelineData() 
        {           
            callSP = $.ajax
            ({
                url: currentListURL,
                method: "GET",
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose;" },
                success: function (data) 
                {
                    // Returning the results
                    var listItems = data.d.results;                         

                    // Loop through items   
                    listItems.forEach( function (entry) 
                    {           
                        console.log(entry);     
                        // Get file name
                        $.ajax
                        ({
                            url: entry.File.__deferred.uri,
                            method: "GET",
                            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose;" },
                            success: function (currentItemFileData) 
                            {
                                var name = currentItemFileData.d.Name;
                                addRowToTable(name);
                            }
                        });

                        function addRowToTable(currentItemFileName) 
                        {
                            // Create vars
                            var name = currentItemFileName || entry.Action || entry.Title;
                            var system = entry.System;
                            var start = entry.Planned_x0020_Start || entry.PM_x0020_Due;
                            var duration = parseInt(entry.Required_x0020_Time_x0020__x0028_hrs_x0029_);
                            var repetitions = parseInt(entry.Repetitions);
                            var frequency = parseInt(entry.Frequency_x0020__x0028_days_x0029_) * 24; // converted to hours
                            var toolTip = toolTipContents(entry,type,name);
                            var executionStatus = entry.Execution_x0020_Status;
                            var color;

                            // Set color by execution status
                            switch(executionStatus)
                            {
                                case "Complete":

                                    color = "#bd25fe";
                                    break;

                                case "In preparation":

                                    color = "#feff3e";
                                    break;

                                case "No longer required":

                                    color = "#fe4763";
                                    break;

                                case "Ready for execution":

                                    color = "#41fe72";
                                    break;

                                default:

                                    color = "gray";
                                    break;
                            }

                            // Add row if fields available
                            if ( start && duration && (executionStatus !== "No longer required") ) 
                            {
                                if ( repetitions && frequency )
                                {
                                    for ( j=0; j<entry.Repetitions; j++ )
                                    {
                                        var actualStart = new Date(start).addHours(frequency * j);
                                        var actualEnd = new Date(actualStart).addHours(duration);

                                        // Add row to dataTable                                                 
                                        dataTable.addRow([system, name, toolTip,color, actualStart, actualEnd]);
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    // Add row to dataTable                                                 
                                    dataTable.addRow([system, name, toolTip,color, new Date(start), new Date(start).addHours(duration)]);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    });         
                },
                error: function (data) 
                {
                    console.log("ERROR: timeline ajax call");
                    console.log(data);
                },
            });
            callSP.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
            {
                // If additional data is available, reinitiate call     
                if (data.d.__next) 
                {
                    currentListURL = data.d.__next;
                    getTimelineData();
                }
                else
                {
                    if ( type == "AP")
                    {
                        type = "PM";
                        currentListURL = PMListURL;
                        getTimelineData();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        console.log("done populating timeline, displaying timeline");
                        toggleLoader("off",1);

                        // Draw timeline
                        dashboard.bind(timelineRangeSlider, timeline);
                        dashboard.draw(dataTable);
                    }
                }
            });
        }           
    }  
}
```

This code is working like a charm, but I can't seem to get the tooltip to stay open when the timeline bar is clicked. Currently, all it does is focus on the bar and the tooltip won't show. If I get rid of the target property, then hovering over the bar will show the tooltip.

My hypothesis is that I may have to go with a dataView instead. Is that true?

How can I get this working?

Comment: The only supported trigger for a Timeline tooltip is `focus` (or `none`):  https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline#configuration-options  That being said, this may help:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32247941/trigger-google-timeline-tooltip-with-selection

Comment: Why is this? You should submit this as an answer by the way.

Comment: @devlin carnate this solution makes the tooltip not interactive. I have links on it that I would like to be able to click. Do you know how to work around that?

Comment: It makes sense that the tooltip would lose interactivity because it's not the actual tooltip, but a facimile of it (from my understanding of the post).  I haven't tried the post to see exactly what kind of element is "cloned", but one idea to add in interactivity would be to use jQuery -- bind a class or id to the tooltip clone, and then use jQuery to handle the event and actions you want.

Comment: P.S.  I don't know why `focus` is the only supported trigger for timeline tooltips.

Comment: @devlincarnate oh one more thing! tooltips no longer show up on hover, is that supposed to happen?